# native messaging android app source code

Tags: android, message

Can any one tell me where I can see the native messaging app source code which come with android if it is open source

I am looking for the source code of following application and version

Application name - Messaging

version - 2.3.6

I have checked this link
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java#ComposeMessageActivity.MsgListMenuClickListener.onMenuItemClick%28android.view.MenuItem%29

Comment: What's the name of the application and for which version of android?

Comment: name of the application is messaging and the version is 2.3.6

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/android-2.3.6_r1/src/com/android/mms/ui/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the link to the latest code for the main screen of the Messaging app:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ConversationList.java

and this is its layout file:
https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/res/layout/conversation_list_screen.xml

Answer (score 4):

The source code of the various pieces of Android are available from github [here](https://github.com/android?tab=repositories).

I found [this](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/tree/gingerbread/src/com/android/mms) that seems to be similar to your request but you should be more precise about the application, maybe the namespace of the application (a string like "com.google.mms.Messaging") otherwise is a bit difficult to find.

Comment: I have written the application name which I got from all application list in the phone

Comment: if you do a `adb shell pm list packages -f` you can obtain the list of all applications installed, choose one of them and then launch it using `adb shell am start com.android.mms` (substitute `com.android.mms` with your choice) and if the application is the one you are asking for then that is the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best native messaging android app source code for anyone to customize

(Its name is [Mesibo](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android): 
[Open Source Messenger App For Android - Real-time Messaging, Voice and Video Calls](https://mesibo.com/)).

> *Mesibo Messenger is an open-source app with real-time messaging, voice and video call features. This repo contains the source code for Mesibo Messenger App for Android. The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android) for iOS version is here.*

**Features**

- One-on-one messaging and Group chat
- High quality voice and video calling
- Rich messaging (text, picture, video, audio, other files)
- Encryption
- Location sharing
- Message status and typing indicators
- Online status (presence) and real-time profile update
- Push notifications

Latest versions are also available through Google Play Store and Apple App Store :

[Get it on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mesibo.mesiboapplication)

---

**Downloading the Source Code**

To download, open a terminal and issue following commands:

```js
$ mkdir Messenger
$ cd Messenger
$ git clone https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android.git
```

Furthermore, If you want more best apps then I recommend:
15 Best Open-Source Encrypted Messaging Android Apps For Privacy Concerned People (2020 List)

1. [Signal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.securesms)
2. [Telegram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.telegram.messenger)
3. [Conversations](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.siacs.conversations)
4. [Xabber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xabber.android)
5. [Antox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=chat.tox.antox)
6. [Kontalk Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kontalk)
7. [Surespot Encrypted Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twofours.surespot)
8. [Linphone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.linphone)
9. [Briar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.briarproject.briar.android)
10. [Wire — Secure Messenger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wire)

All these listed apps are open source and available on GitHub and Playstore. ([Read more here...](https://techlog360.com/open-source-messenger-voip-android-apps/))